# Looking to have a button in google sheets that adds another identical section

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently trying to create a grade tracker on google sheets, I have the sample for an individual class. But the number of classes each person will have may vary. So I want to add a button that a person can click to add an additional class. I have some experience writing python and google scripts. [image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

so your question was worded oddly so I am not sure if I understood it correctly.
I am assuming when you say that not everyone has the same classes that you mean some people might have 5 periods while others might have 6 (as an example). And when you say you want to be able to add new classes. I would imagine you mean that a person could add a **sheet** for each period that they have, all stored within the same spreadsheet file. If that is the case then this code will duplicate that sheet (I named the one being duplicated "Template" for my example). You would simply add this to the script for the spreadsheet.

```
    function onOpen() { //THIS ADDS A BUTTON IN THE MENU BAR SO THAT PEOPLE CAN JUST CLICK THAT BUTTON INSTEAD OF RUNNING THE CODE MANUALLY
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Add Class')
  .addItem('Add another class', 'cloneGoogleSheet')
  .addToUi();
}
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Please enter the name for the class sheet', //ALLOWS THEM TO NAME THE NEW SHEET
      'Ex: period #, class #...',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  var name = text;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template').copyTo(ss);

  /* Before cloning the sheet, delete any previous copy */
  var old = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  if (old) ss.deleteSheet(old); // or old.setName(new Name);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Utilities.sleep(2000);
  sheet.setName(name);

  /* Make the new sheet active */
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

}
```

Now with that being said. I am not sure why you would want to use a google app script to accomplish this. Couldn't you just have the people right click the sheet (at the bottom), then select duplicate, then rename the sheet? If I understood your problem correctly then that would be a much easier way of accomplishing the same thing. I have included some pictures below.

[image]
[image]
[image]